# How to invoke a parameterized constructor of a MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a StoreController, which has to initialize a product repository:

```
public StoreController(IProductRepository productRepository)
        {
            this.productRepository = productRepository;
        }
```

the controller invokes using the parameterless constructor when I call the controller using an ActionLink.:

```
public StoreController()
        {
        }
```

Here is the actionlink that is calling the store controller:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Store", "Index", "Store", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })
```

I tried the code as it is, and the parameterized constructor won't get invoked, instead the normal constructor would get called and the productRepository cannot be used since it is not initialized, and hence I get a null reference error. I have to use the parameterized constructor because the productRepository also uses another parameterized constructor and I cannot create an object and pass that inside the parameterized constructor.

Edit: Here is the private property:

```
private readonly IProductRepository productRepository;
```

and the index method:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        StoreViewModel model = new StoreViewModel();
        model.TopHeadphones = headphonesService.GetTopHeadphones();
        model.Mouse = mouseService.GetTopMouse();
        return View(model) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the parameterless constructor?. If removing the parameterless controller you get an exception, it probably means that you need to register your repository in the Dependency Injection so it can be resolved

btw, it is a good practice to name your pirvate properties with "_" at the beginning "_productRepository" in your case

Comment: Yes I did try to remove the parameterless constructor, and it did not generate an error or exception. Instead the browser window went black and there was no hit to the actual Index method or the parameterized constructor. I have also registered the repository in the dependency injection.

Comment: Could you please update your question so we can see the private property, the constructor (with parameter) and the Index method?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the private property and the index method.

Comment: It seems to be ok. Please confirm the following:
1- You only have the constructor with parameter (remove the parameterless constructor)
2- Set a breakpoint inside the constructor (check if it is called)
3- You have the repository register in the dependency injection.
4- You are not getting any exception (if you receive any, please add the exception here)
If you tried all of this things, please I suggest to paste all your controller here (and also how you register in DI the repository), or upload the project to any github and paste the url so we can check